# How to integrate mysql with Zend framework?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I am completely new to Zend framework. I have database created in MySQL. Now I want to use it together with Zend. Completely confused how to start with. I have gone through many tutorials like http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/ but was confusing. Can anybody help me on how I can accomplish, with this step-by-step instructions or any good tutorial?

Comment: You need to be more specific what exactly did you find confusing. The Zend manuals describe the process - without knowing any details we can only repeat what they're saying there.

Comment: I recommend following [this tutorial](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/). It's a bit outdated, but still is great in teaching the basics of using ZF - and ORM-component in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 Methods to do it:

Command Line:

```
zf configure db-adapter "adapter=PDO_MYSQL&dbname=[your databasename]&host=[your host]&username=[your username]&password=[your password]" -s development
```

or in your application.ini file :

```
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.dbname = "[your database]"
resources.db.params.host = "[your host]"
resources.db.params.username = "[your username]"
resources.db.params.password = "[your password]"
```

any questions? Mention in comment :)

EDIT:

Since you are starting with Zend, firstly, welcome to Zend Framework :)
Here is the tutorial you can refer for initial development:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/zend-framework-from-scratch/

If you directly want to know only about integrating database (i.e. Models - business logic) refer to this link:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/zend-framework-from-scratch-models-and-integrating-doctrine-orm/

PS: Few things in the above links might be deprecated and MAY not work example, the second link talks about ORM as Doctrine whereas we use Doctrine2 now-a-days.

All clear?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Once am done with this how to make a start with simple add, update and delete? Like in core php, we used to write mysql_query(). Any good tutorial with this respect are also welcomed.

Comment: @zennith I have edited my answer so that others can refer to it. If you think it has cleared all your queries, click on tick next to my answer (accept it) so that other's *will* refer to it as well.

Comment: Hey thanks. No haste :). Let me see it to full satisfaction, thereafter for sure will  do mark a tick. For beginners of zend framework i would recommend Zend+netbeans combination. Reference :http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxdvDBXlroY.

Comment: Just for reminder, this is not customer service but, a community `help` !

Comment: yeah :) Thanks for your help. I went through your link and was indeed very helpful :)